# VirtualBox add virtual hard drive to an existing Debian

Tags: virtualbox

I use debian system in VirtualBox. I would like to add to this system, a new virtual hard disk. I went through the wizard, but the system can not see it. How to connect the new drive and format it?

[image]

Comment: You should be able to add a drive, but formatting it is not done from VirtualBox. For that please boot the VM and handle that from inside the VM.

Comment: I would like format this drive from debian, but I don't see this drive in debian.

Comment: @Hennes You can clearly explain?

Comment: Someone already wrote a post for the second part. Can you see if  `lshw -class disk` work for you? if not read up on this post: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4561/how-do-i-find-out-what-hard-disks-are-in-the-system

Comment: Ok, I get it from `lshw` show `/dev/sdb` - 2GB. Now can I format it?

Comment: From inside the VM, what is the output of `fdisk -l`?

Comment: Yes. Either format it and access it 'dangerously dedicated' for set up a partition table first (MBR or GPT. Probably using gpart).

Comment: Formatting the new virtual disk is done the usual way in Linux systems. For instance, you can use `gparted`, a convenient graphical tool.

Comment: I used `mkfs.ext4`